# when relative clauses is needed

Tags: clauses, relative-clauses

Some native speakers corrected sentence A to sentence B in my essay. Could anyone explain why here "brings to" is needed?

> A. The problem of foreign language class at primary school is the distraction to
>   other compulsory subjects
>
> B. The problem of foreign language class at primary school is the distraction it
>   **brings to** other compulsory subjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the word *distraction* (and the verb *distract*) does not take a *to* phrase. (They do optionally take a *from* phrase). These are just facts about the word, not about English grammar in general.

What you wrote is comprehensible, but not natural in English.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but B is more explicit, and might be preferred for that reason.